# Как разрешить файл .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, localhost

Если добавляю файл .htaccess, то сайт падает, в браузере выводится:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

Comment: Мне кажется, надо привести содержание .htaccess, иначе ничего не понятно.

Comment: У меня другой вопрос нарисовался. А зачем *"добавляю файл .htaccess"*, если не понимаю зачем он и что он делает?

Comment: код в студию!

Comment: код чего, файл .htaccess пуст, но из-за него не хочет сайт запускаться, вот такой вот "феномен".

Comment: «More information about this error may be available **in the server error log**.»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конфигах домена от апач должны быть разрешены реврайты:

```
AllowOverride ALL
```

Приведите сюда этот файл конфига. У меня такая же проблема была на VDS, решилась именно этой строкой.

Comment: прописал везде в конфиге AllowOverride ALL, толку мало.

Comment: А! Все, получилось!

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего mod_rewrite в конфигах закомментарен

Comment: Не уверен, но кажется любая ошибка в .htaccess приведет к ошибке 500.

Comment: файл .htaccess вообще пустой. Да, LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so было закомментировано, но после разкомментирования ничего не изменилось.

Comment: И вы тоже помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Если файл **.htaccess** пустой - то удалить его нафиг, если он реально для чего-то нужен то в него эти нужные строчки прописать, иначе ошибка останется.

Ну или пропиши в него

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

А вообще можно скинуть файл логов апача, и там намного понятнее будет из-за чего ошибка вылетает. Без логов ничего не понятно. Вполне возможно что .htaccess нифига не пустой, что в нём присутствует какая-то строка, или сохранен в UTF-8 bom. что вероятнее всего выдаст ошибку. Вариантов могу написать вагон и тележку, а смысл? Код файла сюда, лог апача так же сюда :)

Но все таки возможно в конфиге апача выключено.

Comment: Я же написал что все ок!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно убрать символ `#` в начале строки 156 в `apache\conf\httpd.conf`. И написать `AllowOverride All` на строчках 229, 265, 378 (номера строк могут отличаться).

Comment: Вы бы добавили как идентифицировать строки которые необходимо раскоментировать

Answer (score 1):

Когда в программном продукте существует возможность просмотра лога ошибок, то при возникновении ошибки следует:

1. Перевести текст ошибки в логе и выполнить, что просят, если это не вызывает затруднений;
2. И/или сразу вбить в поисковик кусок текста ошибки в логе и посмотреть, как другие разрешили проблему;
3. Если варианты 1 и 2 не помогли, задавая вопрос, привести в нём текст ошибки в логе.

Конкрентно для Apache — точнее, у меня стоит [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/), в состав которого входит Apache — мне всегда, несколько раз помогал способ 1. Описание ошибок в журнале достаточно подробное и понятное.

Без содержимого лога нельзя точно сказать, в чём состоит проблема, `500 Internal Server Error` может выдаваться по нескольким причинам. Судя по результатам, которые получил я, когда гуглил в поисках разрешения аналогичной проблемы, большей части пользователей помогает замена в файле `httpd.conf` строки  `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` на `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Лично же мне помогло [удаление всех комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504740/199934) в `.htaccess`, решил проблему, разобравшись с логом.