# .htaccess функционирует на удалённом сервере, но не локальном WampServer

Tags: .htaccess, apache, wamp-server

Здравствуйте. На мой компьютер в папку `D:\wamp\www` установлен WampServer Version 2.0 . Её содержимое запускается по адресу `http://localhost/` , но только если в папке не лежит файл `.htaccess` со следующим содержанием:

```
<!-- Кастомная страница 404 -->
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
<!-- Конец кастомной страницы 404 -->

<!-- Скрытие расширений .html -->
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
<!-- Конец скрытия расширений .html -->

<!-- Переадресация index.html на заглавную -->
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://Kristinita.github.io/ [R=301,L]
<!-- Конец переадресации index.html на заглавную -->
```

На сайте он выполняет свои функции, однако если файл `.htaccess` положить в `D:\wamp\www` , при открытии любой страницы через WAMP Server вместо содержимого страницы в браузере выведется ошибка `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

[В интернете](http://www.bsourcecode.com/php/how-to-enable-htaccess-in-wamp-server/) [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718919/500-internal-error-with-rewriteengine-on-htaccess-on-localhost-with-wamp) убрать октоторп в строке файла `httpd.conf` — `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` или же левой кнопкой мыши по <kbd>Aestan Tray Menu</kbd> → <kbd>Apache</kbd> → <kbd>Модули Apache</kbd> → галочка на `rewrite_module` , что по сути одно и то же. Несколько раз сделал → <kbd>Перезапустить все сервисы</kbd> → ошибка 500 никуда не исчезла.

Что необходимо совершить для корректного взаимодействия WampServer с `.htaccess` ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Левой кнопкой мыши по <kbd>Aestan Tray Menu</kbd> → <kbd>Apache</kbd> → <kbd>Журнал ошибок Apache</kbd>. Разобравшись с логами, удалил в `.htaccess` все комментарии. Результат:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://Kristinita.github.io/ [R=301,L]
```

Заработало. Спасибо.