# Помогите решить проблему с кодировкой

Tags: php, mysql

И так у меня есть : 
1 БД(база данных) в phpMyAdmin с кодировкой ut8_general_ci (1 картина).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Таблицы с этой же кодировкой (картина 2)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 Index.php с данным кодом

```
    <?php include ("blocks/bd.php");
$result = $db->query("SELECT title,id,meta_d,meta_k,text,page FROM settings");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $myrow["title"]; ?></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head> 
<body>
<table width="690" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="main_border">
  <?php include ("blocks/header.php"); ?>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <?php include ("blocks/lefttd.php"); ?>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <?php include ("blocks/footer.php"); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

И у меня такая проблема [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не дублируйте вопросы, сначала хотя бы попробуйте поискать и подумайте как верно задать вопрос по сути. Помогите решить проблему - это не вопрос. Здесь возможно есть ответ для вас https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/

Comment: прошу прощения , но я серавно не могу исправить  это, поэтому создал эту тему. ваша ссылка не помогло

Comment: в самом начале скрипта `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: не помогло, прописал в начале как и просили(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первый вариант**

Создайте файл `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

**Второй вариант**

Замените в bd.php `mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8' );` на `$db->set_charset("utf8");`

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "phpblog");
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: по подробнее, где создать и сохранить?

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков этот файл надо поместить в корень сайта, там где находится index-файл (как правило, это index.html или index.php)

Comment: не помогло( спасибо что уделили время

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков вы правильно сохранили?  Здесь можно посмотреть https://myrusakov.ru/php-create-htaccess.html. Это единственный вариант который решить эту проблему

Comment: да я через NotePad++

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков дайте файл db.php

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/694964

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков все решено!

Comment: Как решили? можете написать

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибоооооооо огромное , блин не знаю даже как я вам рад. Счастье в семье, любви да здоровья) я мучался целые сутки

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

1. тег  не устанавливает кодировку, а лишь сообщает браузеру о кодировке
   т.е. если фактически ваш HTML-редактор настроен под кодировку windows-1251, то вы можете хоть двадцать пять раз прописать  - в браузер всё-равно придёт кодировка windows-1251

[это как тег  - сайт вполне может быть по содержанию педофильским,а в этом теге будет что-то о художественно-прекрасном именно так раньше обманывали поисковые системы
поэтому поисковики теперь первым делом сравнивают данные этого тега с фактическими словами в теле сайта и если находят несоответствие между первым и вторым, сразу же относят страницу к сомнительным и существенно понижают её рейтинг]

2. всё это будет нормально работать из-под вашего локального компьютера
   однако, при сохранении на сервере вполне возможна проблема
   дело в том, что в серверном файле `.htaccess` существует команда принудительной установки кодировки, в которую сервер преобразует ВСЕ свои файлы, отдавая их браузерам пользователей и вполне может быть, что там у вас прописано AddDefaultCharset windows-1251 эту строчку вам надо просто удалить - тогда по умолчанию будет utf-8 (а лучше принудительно
   записать `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`)

При создании файла  `.htaccess` нужно [Как разрешить файл .htaccess?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/86226/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-htaccess)

3. есть кодировка соединения с базой данних и кодировка в котой эти данные  храняться в базе. Эти две кодировки так же должны быть указаны.
   Кодировку базы данный нужно указать при создании, а кодировку соединения нужно задавать следующим способом

   `mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
   mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
   mysqli_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");`

или заменить  [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) на [$mysqli->query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) в стиле ООП

4. если кодировка в базе указана как utf8 это не значит что туда нельзя будет записать данные в другой кодировке, возможно возникнут  ошыбки, а возможно проблемы будут уже только при выводе. то есть нужно смотреть откуда данные приходят и в какой кодировке.

Здесь можно почитать что такое кодировка. Чтобы не приходилось смотреть на это как на магию :) [Кодировки: полезная информация и краткая ретроспектива](http://codeharmony.ru/materials/120)

> Упрощенно говоря, кодировка - это таблица сопоставлений символов, которые мы можем видеть на экране, определенным числовым кодам.

Самых символов которые мы видим на экране нету и компъютер не знает про них ничего. зато он знает различные коды и в зависимости от того какой код ему дают он виводит определенный рисунок. Соответсвие между рисунком и кодом это и есть кодировка.

Вы же пытаетесь дать ему символы которые сохранены, закодированые в windows-1251, и потом просто потому что нужно все делать в utf8 говорите ему чтобы он вывел эти коды по таблице utf8. Он выводит, эти коды которые в кодировке windows-1251 есть буквами в utf8 просто отсутсвуют или используються для других символов.

Comment: я импортировал изтаблицу из sql файла (во время импорта в phpMyadmin в вкладке кодировка выбирал Windows-1251, лишь тогда в PhpMyadmin отображались русские буквы в таблице ) а так везде у меня стоит utf8 . Скажите поэтапно прошу, что делать , чтобы решить данную проблему? Заранее спаибо

Comment: я экспортировал таблицы с кодировкой UTF8 и удали все с сервера заново импортировал новый sql файл с кодировкой UTF8 , проблема не решилась(

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/400903

Comment: у вас есть вк? может там решим?

Comment: что вы рекомендуете теперь?

Comment: Спасибо , решил проблему , спасибо за потраченное на меня время