# Не работает кодировка

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает кодировка, есть скрипт, который выводит из таблицы MySQL тот или иной текст. Но выводит он должен его на русском, а выводит "РџСЂРѕС„РёР»СЊ" заместо слов "Профиль". Скрипт на php. Помогите пожалуйста. Подскажите что делать. Текст который уже есть в скрипте идет нормально при кодировки "Windows 2151", но из таблицы как выше написал. В кодировки "UTF-8" текст который есть в скрипте выводит также.

Comment: Настройте кодировку соединения с БД. Сейчас она, вероятно, юникод.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793366/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9/793382#793382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать в начале дополнительный запрос 
    mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");  помогло вот это, спасибо!